# How(where) to change the default directory where WinEdt save new files?

Tags: winedt, options

How (where) to change the default directory where WinEdt save new files?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WinEdt saves new files in the currently active directory.

There's no way to change it for new files.

But there's a couple of options in the "Preferences" dialog (Options menu) -> "File Status" tab -> "Working Directory" to decide when the active directory gets changed:

[image]

---

A workaround exists, **but it works ONLY if you have a favourite directory where you intend to save ALL your new files**.

Let's say this directory is `C:\mydir`. Follow these steps:

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. Double-click the "Main Menu" item (`MainMenu.ini` gets opened)
3. Locate the lines

   ```
     ITEM="New"
       CAPTION="&New"
       IMAGE="New"
       MACRO="NewDoc;"
       SHORTCUT="16462::Ctrl+N"
   ```

   and substitute them with

   ```
     ITEM="New"
       CAPTION="&New"
       IMAGE="New"
       MACRO="SetFolder('C:\mydir');NewDoc;"
       SHORTCUT="16462::Ctrl+N"
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd>

That's it. Now every time you create a new file the active directory is changed to `C:\mydir` and when you save the file you will be prompted with that directory in the "Save As" dialog (unless in the meantime you've changed the active directory somehow).

Answer (score 0):

You may set the default directory;

```
  ITEM="New"
    CAPTION="&New"
    START_FOLDER="D:\mydir"
    IMAGE="New"
    MACRO="NewDoc;"
    SHORTCUT="16462::Ctrl+N"

  ITEM="Open"
    CAPTION="&Open..."
    IMAGE="Open"
    START_FOLDER="D:\mydir" //"%!P"
    MACRO="OpenDoc;"
    SHORTCUT="16463::Ctrl+O"
```